# how make multithread communication between server java and more android clients

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I have met headwind with the development of a communication between a Java server and Android clients.

Any suggestions? My communication single thread code is as below.

TCP SERVER.java:

```
 //public static final int SERVERPORT = 110;

    public static final int SERVERPORT = 4444;
    //public static final int SERVERPORT =  80;

    private boolean running = false;
    private PrintWriter mOut;
    private OnMessageReceived messageListener;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //opens the window where the messages will be received and sent
        ServerBoard frame = new ServerBoard();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    /**
     * Constructor of the class
     *
     * @param messageListener listens for the messages
     */
    public TCPServer(OnMessageReceived messageListener) {
        this.messageListener = messageListener;
    }

    /**
     * Method to send the messages from server to client
     *
     * @param message the message sent by the server
     */
    public void sendMessage(String message) {
        if (mOut != null && !mOut.checkError()) {
            mOut.println(message);
            mOut.flush();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        super.run();

        running = true;

        try {
            System.out.println("S: Connecting...");

            //create a server socket. A server socket waits for requests to come in over the network.
            ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(SERVERPORT);

            //create client socket... the method accept() listens for a connection to be made to this socket and accepts it.
            Socket client = serverSocket.accept();
            System.out.println("S: Receiving...");

            try {

                //sends the message to the client
                mOut = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(client.getOutputStream())), true);

                //read the message received from client
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));

                //in this while we wait to receive messages from client (it's an infinite loop)
                //this while it's like a listener for messages
                while (running) {
                    String message = in.readLine();

                    if (message != null && messageListener != null) {
                        //call the method messageReceived from ServerBoard class
                        messageListener.messageReceived(message);

                        //String gongFile = "/Users/marco/Downloads/JavaSoundDemo/audio/ok.wav";
//                        String gongFile = "src\\tcpserver\\ok.wav";
//
//                       InputStream inn = null;
////
//                        AudioStream audioStream = null;
////                  
//                       // inn=new FileInputStream(new File("/Users/marco/NetBeansProjects/TCPServer/src/tcpserver/ok.wav"));
//                          inn=new FileInputStream(new File("http://www.mircmania.it/suoni/africa.wav"));
////
//                        audioStream=new AudioStream(inn);
//                        AudioPlayer.player.start(audioStream);
                           // String song = "http://www.mircmania.it/suoni/africa.wav";

                         String song = "http://www.mircmania.it/suoni/squillo7.wav";
        //Player mp3player = null;
       // BufferedInputStream inn = null;
        InputStream inn = null;
        AudioStream audioStream = null;
        try {
          inn = new BufferedInputStream(new URL(song).openStream());
          audioStream=new AudioStream(inn);
          AudioPlayer.player.start(audioStream);
         // mp3player = new Player(inn);
         // mp3player.play();
        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
        } catch (IOException e) {
        } catch (NullPointerException ex) {
        }
                    }
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("S: Error");
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                client.close();
                System.out.println("S: Done.");
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("S: Error");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }



    //Declare the interface. The method messageReceived(String message) will must be implemented in the ServerBoard
    //class at on startServer button click
    public interface OnMessageReceived {

        public void messageReceived(String message);
    }

}
```

TCP CLIENT.java:

```
public class TCPClient {

    private String serverMessage;
   /* public static final String SERVERIP = "31.220.16.19"; //your computer IP address
    public static final int SERVERPORT = 110;
*/
    public static final String SERVERIP = "192.168.1.38"; //your computer IP address
    public static final int SERVERPORT = 4444;
/*public static final String SERVERIP = "87.7.183.222"; //your computer IP address
    public static final int SERVERPORT =  4444;*/
    private OnMessageReceived mMessageListener = null;
    private boolean mRun = false;
    PrintWriter out;
    BufferedReader in;

    /**
     *  Constructor of the class. OnMessagedReceived listens for the messages received from server
     */
    public TCPClient(OnMessageReceived listener) {
        mMessageListener = listener;
    }

    /**
     * Sends the message entered by client to the server
     * @param message text entered by client
     */
    public void sendMessage(String message){
        if (out != null && !out.checkError()) {
            out.println(message);
            out.flush();
        }
    }

    public void stopClient(){
        mRun = false;
    }

    public void run() {

        mRun = true;

        try {
            //here you must put your computer's IP address.
            InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVERIP);
            //InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
            //System.out.println(serverAddr.toString());

            Log.e("TCP Client", "C: Connecting...");

            //create a socket to make the connection with the server
            Socket socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);

            try {

                //send the message to the server
                out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())), true);

                Log.e("TCP Client", "C: Sent.");

                Log.e("TCP Client", "C: Done.");

                //receive the message which the server sends back
                in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

                //in this while the client listens for the messages sent by the server
                while (mRun) {
                    serverMessage = in.readLine();

                    if (serverMessage != null && mMessageListener != null) {
                        //call the method messageReceived from MyActivity class
                        mMessageListener.messageReceived(serverMessage);
                    }
                    serverMessage = null;

                }

                Log.e("RESPONSE FROM SERVER", "S: Received Message: '" + serverMessage + "'");

            } catch (Exception e) {

                Log.e("TCP", "S: Error", e);

            } finally {
                //the socket must be closed. It is not possible to reconnect to this socket
                // after it is closed, which means a new socket instance has to be created.
                socket.close();
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {

            Log.e("TCP", "C: Error", e);

        }

    }

    //Declare the interface. The method messageReceived(String message) will must be implemented in the MyActivity
    //class at on asynckTask doInBackground
    public interface OnMessageReceived {
        public void messageReceived(String message);
    }
}
```

MAIN ACTIVITY.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    private ListView mList;
    private ArrayList<String> arrayList;
    private MyCustomAdapter mAdapter;
    private TCPClient mTcpClient;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();

        final EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        Button send = (Button)findViewById(R.id.send_button);

        //relate the listView from java to the one created in xml
        mList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
        mAdapter = new MyCustomAdapter(this, arrayList);
        mList.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        // connect to the server
        new connectTask().execute("");

        send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                String message = editText.getText().toString();

                //add the text in the arrayList
                arrayList.add("c: " + message);

                //sends the message to the server
                if (mTcpClient != null) {
                    mTcpClient.sendMessage(message);
                }

                //refresh the list
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                editText.setText("");
            }
        });

    }

    public class connectTask extends AsyncTask<String,String,TCPClient> {

        @Override
        protected TCPClient doInBackground(String... message) {

            //we create a TCPClient object and
            mTcpClient = new TCPClient(new TCPClient.OnMessageReceived() {
                @Override
                //here the messageReceived method is implemented
                public void messageReceived(String message) {
                    //this method calls the onProgressUpdate
                    publishProgress(message);
                }
            });
            mTcpClient.run();

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);

            //in the arrayList we add the messaged received from server
            arrayList.add(values[0]);
            // notify the adapter that the data set has changed. This means that new message received
            // from server was added to the list
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `System.out.println("S: Connecting...");`. Wrong. Servers do not connect. They start listening and waiting for clients to connect.

Comment: `Socket client = serverSocket.accept();`. Put all code AFTER that statement in a so called ClienThread. Then just start that thread.

Comment: my code works for communication single thread.....i ask how make communication multithread :)

Comment: Yes. I understood that from the beginning. So thats why i told you what you had to do. It is not that difficult :-).

Comment: look at the first item in https://www.google.ru/search?newwindow=1&espv=2&q=java+multithreaded+server+example

Comment: Well that article is nothing new. Just as i described it here. Pretty strange reaction of ZEUS. Would be nice if he cleared things up.